# Looking for a Regular Expression that will allow me to everything after the second occurrence of "/"

Tags: regex, bash

Starting with a file that has 1 to multiple lines that look something like this:

```
0a090s909afd09f     refs/heads/feature/branch-123
0a090s909afd09f     refs/heads/branch-124
```

I want to read the file line by line and print to another file everything after the second "/":

```
feature/branch-123
branch-124
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bash` parameter expansion,

```
#!/bin/bash

# Reset IFS and parse line not allowing decoding of any backslash escaped 
# characters, '-r' flag in 'read' takes care of it
while IFS= read -r line
do 
    printf "%s\n" "${line#*/*/}"
done<file
```

Or in a single line, as

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "${line#*/*/}"; done<file
feature/branch-123
branch-124
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open for `awk` :

```
awk -F'/' '{$1=$2=""}1' inputfile
  feature branch-123
  branch-124
```

If `grep` is acceptable:

```
grep -oP '/.*?/\K.*' file
feature/branch-123
branch-124
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/([^/]*\/){2}//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'heads\/' '{print $2}' file 

feature/branch-123
branch-124
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed 's|^[^/]*/[^/]*/||' your_input_file
```

(A note, I used `|` as separator instead of the normal `/` in sed, in order to avoid cumbersome escapes)

The regex should be trivial to understand:

```
^[^/]*/[^/]*/

^              Start of line
 [^/]*         Any number of non-slash character
      /        a slash
       [^/]*   Any number of non-slash character
            /  a slash
```

The above string is replaced with nothing, which leave you what's following the 2nd slash.